# How to show help in Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, design-guidelines

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 app and it shows a result which uses a color coding scheme. I want to show a help for the users on the color coding scheme. But how to display this help? I don't know the design guidelines about displaying help in Windows Phone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Guidelines for app help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465049.aspx) and [Guidelines for designing instructional UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn440595.aspx) might be helpful.

https://ux.stackexchange.com is more suitable for questions regarding UX.